# Android Studio getting value out of listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

```
private  void populateListView(){
    Cursor c = loginDataBaseAdapter.allData();

    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] fromfields = new String[]{"_id", "NAME", "YEAR", "GENRE"};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.TVmovieID, R.id.TVmovieTtile, R.id.TVmovieYear, R.id.TVmoviegenre};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.mlayout, c, fromfields, toViewIDs);
    lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String s = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(Proba.this, "String"+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is a method I call onCreate of this Activity, I use toast just to make sure that im getting the right value, but I get the android.database.sqlite... . I want to get the value of just one field, but first I want to get the value of the whole list.

Comment: cast `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` to `Cursor` ... then use it

Comment: It worked, i used Integer i = cursor.getInt(1); since I need the value of the first column(id). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of implementation to get any fields

```
final String[] fromfields = new String[]{"_id", "NAME", "YEAR", "GENRE"};
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Cursor cursor = myCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(fromfields[1])
        String name = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        Toast.makeText(Proba.this, "Name is " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```